# What is the continuity of Government chain of succession for the People's Republic of China?

Tags: china, succession, political-leaders

Many countries have protocols in place which determine who the successor to the leadership of that country will be in the event that one or more of the leaders or their successors die.

What is the PRC's chain of succession?  How is the chain of succession determined?

At what point of simultaneous removal of political office holders or those appointed by them does the chain of succession become unclear even to the Chinese? Who is likely to be in charge at that point?

**EDIT**

To make this more clear, I'm talking about a potential assassination and/or terrorist action that more-or-less simultaneously removes the Paramount Leader and a variable number of his successors.  I'm interested in knowing who could take immediate, emergency, leadership of the nation and have the power to act to resolve the state of emergency.  Don't tell me that there *wouldn't* be a state of emergency if the Paramount Leader and a lot of his successors were killed.

Restoring the day-to-day government is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in Russian sources:

- First successor is his deputy (vice-chairman of the PRC).
- Second successor is the Chairman of the All-China Assembly of People's Representatives (legislature).

The constitution does not specify further successors but I assume the further successor should be the deputy of the Chairman of the Assembly (at least it is the logic one would employ in the USSR).